# htmlparsing in a loop with a large list (18000 urls)

Tags: r

I'm new to R and have been trying to do some figure out what I can do to move this along.  I know loops are not the best thing to use, but it's all I can figure out.  I've searched the here and the net, and am seeing options like tapply, but I can't figure out if it's something I'm doing wrong, or if tapply isn't compatible with this type of data.  I think it's the latter, but I'm new and what do I know.  HA!

I have a data.frame that holds all the players that have played from a previous parse that amounts to over 18000 rows.  The script below takes that url and scrapes another URL if they played last year.  Is there anything a I can do to make this quicker or less of a memory pig, as it routinely pegs my ram at 99% after around 15 minutes?  Thanks for any help!

```
#GET YEARS PLAYED LINKS


yplist = NULL

playerURLs <- paste("http://www.baseball-reference.com",datafile[,c("hrefs")],sep="")

for(thisplayerURL in playerURLs){

doc <- htmlParse(thisplayerURL)
yplinks <- data.frame(
  names =  xpathSApply(doc, '//*[@id="all_standard_batting"]/div/ul/li[2]/ul/li[. = "2014"]/a',xmlValue),
  hrefs = xpathSApply(doc, '//*[@id="all_standard_batting"]/div/ul/li[2]/ul/li[. = "2014"]/a',xmlGetAttr,'href'))

yplist = rbind(yplist, yplinks)

}

yplist[,c("hrefs")]
```

Example datafile list in playerURLs (there are 2 mel queens, is different)

```
  X  names      hrefs
1 1 Jason Kipnis /players/k/kipnija01.shtml
2 2 Tom Qualters /players/q/qualtto01.shtml
3 3 Paul Quantrill /players/q/quantpa01.shtml
4 4 Bill Quarles /players/q/quarlbi01.shtml
5 5 Billy Queen /players/q/queenbi01.shtml
6 6 Mel Queen /players/q/queenme01.shtml
7 7 Mel Queen /players/q/queenme02.shtml
```

If anyone of those guys played in 2014 my script above would return a data.frame that looks like the following

```
  X  names      hrefs
1 1 Jason Kipnis players/gl.cgi?id=kipnija01&t=b&year=2014
2 2 Tom Qualters /players/gl.cgi?id=qualtto01&t=b&year=2014
3 3 Paul Quantrill /players/gl.cgi?id=quantpa01&t=b&year=2014
4 4 Bill Quarles /players/gl.cgi?id=quarlbi01&t=b&year=2014
5 5 Billy Queen /players/gl.cgi?id=queenbi01&t=b&year=2014
6 6 Mel Queen /players/gl.cgi?id=queenme01&t=b&year=2014
7 7 Mel Queen /players/gl.cgi?id=queenme02&t=b&year=2014
```

Comment: Could you post some of your data (like the first 100 rows) so we can reproduce your example?

Comment: IANAL but what you are doing is in violation of item 2 in their [TOS](http://www.sports-reference.com/termsofuse.shtml). If so, anyone who helps is also in violation.

Comment: your ram pegs at 99% ? What is the size of your ram?

Comment: 16 gb. I'd like to see if I can get an answer for future reference, but it does look like @hrbrmstr is correct though.